# ZIP +4 with Randoms

Tags: ssis

I have a file that I receive from a Wholesaler that I am trying to import into SQL for Reporting. 
It has a Zip Code column but some (not all) of the Zip Codes have +4 to them. 
I have the data running through a lookup to attach a Sales Region and a District Manager based on Postal Code.

The problem I am encountering is that the code I'm using;

```
LEFT(ZIP,5)
```

Works great if the Zip Code has a +4 but for some reason if it doesnt it is returning a blank.

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

- I want to keep this in an SSIS Expression and I am not familiar with the Script Task yet.

Comment: The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231081.aspx) says `LEFT works only with the DT_WSTR data type` and although it should cast it implicitly, you may have to cast it yourself. Try [SUBSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx) if you can't get LEFT to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of the zips have +4 data and others don't, it would offer flexibility to substring these out into separate columns. The derived column transformation does this well and would allow you to do it within your data flow. Once you have them in your database, you can concatenate the two columns to regain the zip+4 data, or you use only the standard zip. This would also allow you to continue doing the lookup as needed.